# Forcing SSL and WWW using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl

I would like to know if this code in .htaccess for forcing SSL and WWW in URL is correct, because with another code I usually get redirect loop, e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` and now it works like a charm (suspiciously). Also, is it possible to write it better/simpler?

```
# Force to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this works. Do you have some special setup such that HTTPS requests all have a non-standard `HTTPS: 1` header?

Comment: Only this code do that job correctly, but I don't know what this mean - `RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !1`

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing with `RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !1` is checking whether the **`HTTPS`** header is present in the request and if it is, then the value *is not* `1`.

> `%{HTTP:header}`, where header can be any *`HTTP MIME-header`* name,
>   can always be used to obtain the value of a header sent in the HTTP
>   request. Example: `%{HTTP:Proxy-Connection}` is the value of the *HTTP
>   header* `Proxy-Connection:`.

Though, I think it'd be easier to [use `%{HTTPS}` instead](//httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

> #### `%{HTTPS}`
>
> Will contain the text "*on*" if the connection is using SSL/TLS, or
>   "*off*" otherwise. (**This variable can be safely used regardless of
>   whether or not `mod_ssl` is loaded**).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Also, you are not using `QSA` flag. This might cause in undesired behaviour.